# Format error messages in validation summary

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, format, data-annotations

I have a validation summary that displays the following html

```
<div class="validation-summary-errors" data-valmsg-summary="true">
    <span>Une ou plusieurs erreurs sont survenues.</span>
    <ul>
      <li>Le champ Nom d'utilisateur est requis.</li>
      <li>Le champ Mot de passe est requis.</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The error messages are the default ones from the dataannotation's required attribute :
They are localized by the requiredfield attribute and the localization

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Username", Prompt = "Username", ResourceType = typeof(Localized))]
public String Username { get; set; }

[Required]
[Display(Name = "Password", Prompt = "Password", ResourceType = typeof(Localized))]
public String Password { get; set; }
```

in my view :

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Username)
```

is giving

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="Le champ Nom d'utilisateur est requis."     id="Username" name="Username" type="text" value="" class="input-validation-error">
```

**What I'd like to achieve is to have in the validation summary**

```
<ul>
   <li>Le champ <span>Nom d'utilisateur</span> est requis.</li>
   <li>Le champ <span>Mot de passe</span> est requis.</li>
</ul>
```

So I guess in the input I would have

```
data-val-required="Le champ <span>Nom d'utilisateur</span> est requis."
```

I'd like to avoid to replace all the Required attributes so I'm looking for a way to do this globally, I was looking the DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter method but I'm not sure it's what I'm looking for.

Does somebody has a clue of how to achieve that ?

Comment: check out the microsoft unobstrusive validation code and see where they render the validation summary, check whether you can give some handler for custom html :)

Comment: Thanks, but I think the messages are coming like this from the server (generated using the dataannotations). 
In the unobtrusive validation code it takes the errors from the data-attributes and append them to the validationsummary from what I undestand

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find a suitable answer to my question,

So I ended up by building a simple attribute that inherit the RequiredAttribute and override the FormatErrorMessage method

```
public sealed class FormattedRequiredAttribute : RequiredAttribute
{
    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
       return base.FormatErrorMessage("<span>"+name+"</span>");
    }
}
```

and I replaced all the [Required] attributes by a [FormattedRequired] attribute